# Run-time error 13 Type Mismatch, Transferring data from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a button in Access (2003) that transfers data to Excel (also 2003).  It opens the Excel workbook, then cycles through the Access subforms and transfers data.

To give more information on how this works, Excel has a range called "Tables" which contains the names of the Access subforms ("Main", "Demographics", "History", etc).  Excel also has a range for each of the names in that first range.  For example, the range "Demographics" contains a series of field names ("FirstName", "LastName", etc).  So the first loop moves through the subforms, and the nested loop moves through the field names.  Each field then passes the value in it over to excel.  Excel also has ranges for "Demographics_Anchor" and "History_Anchor" etc, which is the first value in the column next to each range (ie the range Demographics has firstname, lastname, and to the right is where the data would go.  So the first item in the range is FirstName, to the right "Demographics_Anchor" is where firstname will go.  Then LastName goes to Demographics_Anchor offset by 1 - or 1 cell down from the anchor).

```
Dim ThisForm As Form
Dim CForm As Object
Dim CTab As TabControl
Dim CControl As Control
Dim CurrentTab As Variant
Dim CControlName As Variant
Dim CControlValue As String
Dim Code As Control
Dim counter1 As Integer

Dim appExcel As Object
Dim Anchor As Object
Dim PageRange As Object
Dim ControlNameRange As Object

strpath = "C:\blah\blah\filename.xlsm"

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open Filename:=strpath, UpdateLinks:=1, ReadOnly:=True

Set wbk = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook

Set PageRange = appExcel.Range("Tables")

'set Access environment
Set ThisForm = Forms("frmHome")
Set CTab = ThisForm.Controls("Subforms")

'export the data from Access Forms to Excel
For Each CurrentTab In PageRange
    If CurrentTab = "Main" Then
        Set CForm = ThisForm
    Else
        CTab.Pages(CurrentTab).SetFocus
        Set CForm = ThisForm.Controls(CurrentTab & " Subform").Form
    End If

    Set ControlNameRange = appExcel.Range(CurrentTab)
    Set Anchor = appExcel.Range(CurrentTab & "_Anchor")

    counter1 = 0
    For Each CControlName In ControlNameRange
        Set CControl = CForm.Controls(CControlName)
        CControl.SetFocus
        Anchor.Offset(RowOffset:=counter1).Value = CControl.Value
        counter1 = counter1 + 1

    Next CControlName

Next CurrentTab
```

I hope this explains what is going on in the code.  I just can't figure out why this keeps bombing out with type mistmatch (error 13).

The data DOES transfer.  It goes through the entire code and every piece of data correctly gets transferred over.  It bombs out at the end as if it goes through the code 1 last time when it shouldn't.  I did confirm that every range is correct and doesn't contain any null values.  The code bombs out on this line: Set CControl = CForm.Controls(CControlName) which is towards the bottom of the second loop.

Please help!  I've spent weeks working with this code and had no luck.  This exact code works in every other database I've worked with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the name of the control `CControlName` from your Excel Range, but then setting the value of this control to the control on the Access form `Set CControl = CForm.Controls(CControlName)`. From this, the most likely explanation is probably that the `CControlName` isn't actually on the Access form (perhaps a typo?).

In the VBA IDE, go under the Tools Menu, select Options and then select the General tab. Under the Error Trapping section, select the "Break on All Errors" option and click "OK" to set the preference. Run your code again; when an error is encountered VBA will stop processing on the line that caused the error. Check the value of `CControlName` and make sure it actually exists on the Access form.

Comment: I don't have experience with error handling.  Thank you for pointing out how to turn this on.  Can you please elaborate on how I can see the value of CControlName?  It gave me the error as usual, but I don't see anywhere where I can view values of variables.  Is there something I can turn on that will show these things?  Thanks!

Comment: Ohh!!!  You hover over the variable and it displays it.  That is fantastic!  I can stop using tons of MsgBoxes throughout my code.  THANK YOU!!!  This solved my problem and I found the problem.  You were correct, one of my fields had a typo.